# Error 1009, I don't really understand why it happens

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, function, class, inventory

I want to display item names when the mouse is over them. And item name variable is in item class. I have an object called apple on the scene. I named it "Apple" in the code. When I call for itemName in a function on the same code, it says it's not defined when I mouseover the object. If I trace the apple.itemName outside the function, it works. I don't know why. This is my code:

The code on my scene:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import inventory.inventorySystem;
import inventory.item;

var IS:inventorySystem;
var IT:item;

apple.itemName = "Apple";
apple.itemIcon = new AppleIcon();
apple.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, showItemNameF);

function showItemNameF(Event:MouseEvent){
    var itemNameBox:TextField;
    itemNameBox.text = this.itemName;
    itemNameBox.x = mouseX;
    itemNameBox.y = mouseY;
}
```

The item class:

```
package inventory {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class item extends MovieClip{

            public var itemName:String;
        public var itemIcon:MovieClip;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in your event handler function does not refer to your apple instance. (Are you coming from AS2 maybe?) `this` is the reference to your class/timeline where your listener code is located and which does not have any itemName variable defined. To be able to retrieve the name you would have to do something like:

```
Apple(e.currentTarget).itemName //assuming that Apple is your class of the apple instance.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, as you said, it worked very well but I really don't understand what it does. I understand the problem that 'this' relates to the timeline not to the class but what is 'item(e.currentTarget)' doing exactly?

Comment: event.currentTarget returns you the object that your event listener is attached to, in your case that would mean the apple instance (you have apple.addEventListener <- so it would be that object). Actaully e.currentTarget should be Event.currentTarget in your code as you use 'Event' as param name. Don't do that, btw, capitalized first letter is used for class names, you should use a lowercase first in this case.

Comment: yeah, I noticed that and changed my Event to only e. Now I understand the deal. I have another problem, why can't I assign same class to more than on object. I thought it was possible.. Now I added a pear object to the scene and trying to make another item but I can't make its class 'item'.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean, but considering this is another topic, you should consider creating a new questions and explain it there better.